# Import data from multiple URLs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import data from several different URLs dynamically from a list on another worksheet. The code pasted below works to import one but need to loop through several different Urls.

- All the newly created tables(which are linked to different URLs should be created on the same sheet consecutively one after another.

Anyone has any ideas on how to do that? or maybe an easier or better idea on how i can make this happen?

Million Thanks & kind regards to all

```
Sub test()
'
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?f=sec_basicmaterials&v=121""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data2, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""No."", Int64.Type}, {""Ticker"", type text}, {""Market Cap"", type te" & _
        "xt}, {""P/E"", type text}, {""Fwd P/E"", type text}, {""PEG"", type text}, {""P/S"", type text}, {""P/B"", type text}, {""P/C"", type text}, {""P/FCF"", type text}, {""EPS this Y"", type text}, {""EPS next Y"", type text}, {""EPS past 5Y"", type text}, {""EPS next 5Y"", type text}, {""Sales past 5Y"", type text}, {""Price"", type number}, {""Change"", Percentage.Typ" & _
        "e}, {""Volume"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Range("a10").Select
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it a different way.  Please try and feedback.

```
' XMLHTTP request:

Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, hTable As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("tbody")(9)
        WriteTable hTable, 1, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As Object, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In tRow
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub
```